# Message: Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using Rails 6.1 and Ruby 3.0, and on top of this error, I'm also getting this error about an uninitialized constant Devise, whenever I run rspec on article_spec.rb.

article_spec.rb looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'


RSpec.describe Article, type: :model do
  # let(:user) { User.create(email: 'levi@gmail.com', password: '123456', password_confirmation: '123456', username:"levi") }
  let(:article) { Article.create(user_id:1, title:"Mike likes big muscles", text: "Big muscles like Mike" ) }
  it "is valid with valid attributes" do
    expect(Article.new).not_to be_valid
  end
end
```

Here's the full trace:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/article_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

NameError:
  uninitialized constant Devise
# ./config/initializers/devise.rb:11:in `<main>'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:681:in `block in load_config_initializer'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:205:in `instrument'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:680:in `load_config_initializer'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:634:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:633:in `each'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:633:in `block in <class:Engine>'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
# /Users/niko/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:384:in `initialize!'
# ./config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/models/article_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: did you install gem `devise` ?

Comment: please share what's in `./config/initializers/devise.rb`